# Cannot find my controllers same file var controllersModule = require

Tags: angularjs, controllers

I am using this seemingly great template as a seed project but can't seem to find a way to add new controllers.

There is a config files which initialises my views:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function OnConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
  .state('Home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl as home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    title: 'Home'
  })
  .state('Blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    controller: 'BlogCtrl as blog',
    templateUrl: 'blog.html',
    title: 'Blog'
  })

  .state('About', {
    url: '/about',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl as about',
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    title: 'About'
  })


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}

module.exports = OnConfig;
```

The HTML part of the views are located in a views directory for example: `views/about.html`

Then the controllers are located and distributed from a js\controllers directory where I have an _index.js file with the following code:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');
var bulk = require('bulk-require');

module.exports = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

bulk(__dirname, ['./**/!(*_index|*.spec).js']);
```

And I am adding my controllers to this controllers.js in the same directory:

```
'use strict';

var controllersModule = require('./_index');

controllersModule.controller("AboutCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this;
    blog.title = 'ABOUT PAGE!';
    blog.intro = "Everything you wanted to know";
    blog.content = "Sed possit legendos ne, mea at magna adhuc, cum et affert diceret eleifend. Qui esse oratio accusamus eu, nostro urbanitas eu nam, nam in erat corpora sadipscing."

});

controllersModule.controller("HomeCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Home Sweet Home';
    vm.number = "Number One for You";
    vm.intro = "Some text"

});

controllersModule.controller("BlogCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this;
    blog.title = 'This is The Blog Homepage!';
    blog.intro = "Blob"

});
```

Only the home controller is being picked up for some reason. Code for the home.html is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <h2 class="heading -large">{{ home.title }}</h2>
    <p class="intro">{{home.intro}}</p>
</div>
```

The HTML for the other controlls follow the same standard:

```
<h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
<h2>{{blog.intro}}</h1>
<p class="intro">{{blog.content}}</p>
```

All of this gets compiled into a views gulp task:

```
'use strict';

var config         = require('../config');
var gulp           = require('gulp');
var browserSync    = require('browser-sync');
var templateCache  = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Views task
gulp.task('views', function() {
  var assets = useref.assets();

  // Put our index.html in the dist folder
  gulp.src('app/index.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.root));

  // Process any other view files from app/views
  return gulp.src(config.views.src)
    .pipe(templateCache({
      standalone: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.views.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ once: true }));

});
```

But I am unable to see why the AboutCtrl and BlogCtrl are not populating the about.html and blog.html pages. Is there something in the code above which stands out?

Comment: keep using undefined object `blog` in your controllers after you declare `var vm=this`. Alias in view has nothing to do with whatever variable name you use in controller to store reference to `this`. Look at errors thrown in browser console

Comment: Hey Charlietfl! This was the problem! I left it there whilst copying which was stupid! Many it thanks, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using undefined objects within the controllers. The aliases in view have no bearing on variables names used in controllers to store reference to `this`.

Change:

```
controllersModule.controller("BlogCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this;
    blog.title = 'This is The Blog Homepage!';
    blog.intro = "Blob";    
});
```

To

```
controllersModule.controller("BlogCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'This is The Blog Homepage!';
    vm.intro = "Blob";
});
```